# Does biometric passport in Ukraine discard foreign passport and an old passport altogether?

Tags: visas, passports

An agreement between EU and Ukraine was signed today. If I get a biometric passport does it discard now my old ones? Soon I am going to Europe (for example to the sea in Greece as soon as the borders will be open for non-visa travel). But that implies biometric passport of Ukraine. Is it worth making it now?
And if the discard sitiation is in place then which information will be lost from the old passports (separate identity number lost, by engraving in ePassport).

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  I am not sure I can understand the situation with the biometric passport.

Comment: Ukraine signed agreement with EU but it doesn't mean that you are in Schengen zone now

Comment: @MikkaRin That's yet another question. Ukraine is extremely unlikely to join Schengen in the near future but visa-free travel to either the Schengen area or the EU as a whole could be granted without that (there is a process called “visa liberalisation dialogue” for that). As far as I know, we aren't there yet either however.